# Corda to share Sequencing between Nodes [1,2 ..]

Tags: corda

I'm trying to figure out Corda Sequencing to be able to make a sequence of ID's eg. 1,2,3 for 2 nodes.

Use Case :- 
Node A. and Node B is in a transaction Node A will want to follow Node B's sequencing number generated by Node B so when Node A creates the First State it would be `100000001` and the next state if Node B has created another Order with Node C, Node A would be able to detect and get the next sequence number e.g. `100000003` and create the order.

- I have tried to figure several methods to address this one is to use
  a off-chain DB ( on node B ) sequencing to perform this act, but the
  problem of creating a custom Sequence is any random ping call from
  any source would be able to increase the sequence index by 1.
- I have also thought of using `flowSession` to ping Corda ledger to 
  obtained a stored no. for indexing my new state. But also it leads to 
  the same problem as above.
- I also though of creating a random no. in Node A where Node B will 
  obtain their own sequencing later and override the number with the new 
  number, but this is not doable due to when creation the ID must be 
  consistent and cannot be randomly changed during the lifecycle of the 
  state.

Please note that the ID suggested is not Corda's linear ID it is just an external ID for users point of view.

Any Good solutions/suggestions for this?

Comment: So it isn't the case that both Node A and Node B are parties to every transaction that increases the sequencing number?

Comment: yes it is! accordance to Node B sequence though

Answer (score 0):

You could create a state just for holding the sequencing number.

- Make all the nodes participants of this state so they get updated whenever the sequence is incremented.
- Write your contract code such that the sequence state needs to be part of each transaction and is incremented correctly.
- All the nodes can find the current sequence now by querying their Vault for the sequence state.